# Help me determine the strength of my coffee

Tags: espresso, moka, nespresso, strength

I drink coffee from a Nespresso Machine (Nespresso Pixie).

I use one capsule of Ristretto Italiano (black), but run it twice under the 'Lungo' option.

Thus my question is: 
What is the strength of the cup I am getting (it'll be weaker than an espresso)? And what other brewing method can give me the same result? Moka pot? Drip coffee?

Comment: You're asking an impossible question to answer as it depends a lot on your water. But yes, your brew will almost definitely be weaker than espresso because there is less coffee in a Nespresso pod than in a normal espresso dose and much less than in a double dose.

Comment: But is it still stronger than the coffee I'll get using a Moka Pot? (regardless of water and other micro factors)

Comment: That depends on which pot. But moka pot is probably stronger, again because of amount of coffee used. A Nespresso pod has only 5 grams of coffee in it. It's not a miracle machine.

Comment: Bialetti 3 cup pot. I'm not expecting the Nespresso to do miracles, just trying to estimate its strength.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: I bought a moka pot. Indeed it is stronger and way more tasty than the Nespresso capsules.

A longer answer: I was using the black capsuls which are designed for espresso size cup, but ran it twice in Lungo mode, thus I assumed I'm getting a weaker coffee.

However, I started questioning the quality of these capsules after getting a free sample of cocoa capsules. The smell was spot on, but the taste quite lackluster. By an interesting coincidence, I had an actual cocoa bag at home and brew myself a proper cocoa on a stove with milk, and the final result was a night and day to the capsules.

After that, I went to a friend who has the spinning Vertuo machine, which makes coffee designed for bigger cups. Sicne I was deluding mine, I assumed the coffee from that machine will be stronger, but it was quite similar to mine.

Compared to those, the moka pot, like the cocoa, has a proper rich taste and strength. Even when I make it "on the weaker side", it still beats the capsules by miles, which tastes like coffee dust rather than proper coffee.

Now, I'm not saying capsules are bad, and I guess they are more tastey than instand coffee, but they don't come any closer to fresh grinded coffee made in a moka pot (like bottled orange juice compared to a freshly squized one).

Of course, all said here is my pure subjective opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The Lungo option is a weaker setting and is still meant to be run ONCE. You run the Lungo option and use a coffee cup slightly larger than the Expresso cup. Nespresso is NOT meant to make a regular cup of coffee ever. It makes Expresso (40ml or 1.4 fluid ounces ounces) or Lungo (110ml or 3.7 fluid ounces). Also not all capsules can be used for Lungo since some are meant for weak Expressos. Get yourself a Coffee Press for regular coffee.

Another Option is make a Lungo and use Expresso to control strength of coffee. So one Lungo and 1 Express will make a medium strength small cup of coffee. Also certain brands like Bustelo capsules make very strong Expresso and Nice Lungo.

Comment: How does a Moka Pot compares to those?

Comment: A Nespresso capsule contains just 5.5 grams of coffee. To get 40 grams of product out of 5.5 grams of coffee means it's a 1:7 ratio when an actual espresso has a 1:2 ratio. A lungo has a 1:3 ratio, so these Nespresso options are far from real espresso or lungos. ;)